# ComputedFactors.profitPercentage -> detectionData.aggFields.profitPrecent

Tags: scala

What is the meaning of -> in the case of SCALA code?
ComputedFactors.profitPercentage -> detectionData.aggFields.profitPrecent

Comment: Please post the full code sample.

Comment: It is probably creating a tuple `foo -> bar` is just sugar syntax for `(foo, bar)` - Unless, `foo` defines a `->` method itself.